# unable to store hindi text in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, centos, java-7, plesk

I am geting data stored as ¥à¤¨à¥ à¤à¤°à¤¨à¥ in mysql . It works fine in localhost but in remote mysql (in plesk) it is not working.
 i have used the following:

```
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

in servlet and

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectkkm?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","root","");
```

in database connection

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

in jsp

Now as per my research i found that the problem is in Java.
java for linux do not support hindi text see url: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

[see this snapshot from oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trq7n.png)

In my localhost (Windows) its work fine but when I deploy it to the centos(linux ) platform its not working.
I think the problem may be in window/linux compatibility.

Can anybody help me to handle this. I am sure problem is not from mysql side.

Comment: So a great quest to explore  mysql encoding/charset/collation options begins

Comment: Are you sure the request object is UTF-8 encoded?  Dump the headers and see.  Also check the encoding on any fields, they might be encoded differently.

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Try adding,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in web.xml

Comment: Which web container you using? I was assuming tomcat so this class file is provided by the container. If the container is different then the library file will be specific to that container. Or you should include the jar containing this class.

Comment: I am using apache tomcat

Comment: Then, is it missing <meta charset="utf-8"> in jsp page. And for me the mysql connection string is useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8 . In yours there is 'yes' instead of 'true'

Comment: In my localhost window platform its work fine but when I deploy it to the centos(linux) its not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your remote db is not configured properly.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

should show

```
character_set_client      utf8                     
character_set_connection   utf8               
character_set_database      utf8                
character_set_filesystem  binary                    
character_set_results        utf8                        
character_set_server         utf8                        
character_set_system       utf8
```

If not you should fix you /etc/mysql/my.cnf

add the following configs in the [mysqld] section

```
character-set-server = utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

put in the [client] and [mysqldump] sections:

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

restart mysql after that

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Connector URIEncoding="utf-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

use above code in your tomcat apache server config file